# Как стилизовать темную тему, когда включена галочка в chrome://flags Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents и под Samsung Internet в режиме затемнения

Tags: javascript, css

Есть в хроме возможность включить такой режим, но с ним не применяются стили с медиа запросом prefers-color-scheme и в Samsung Internet ничего не работает, хотя написано, что поддерживается. Как стилизовать можно?

[image: chrome://flags]

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=prefers-color-scheme
Возможно версия вашего браузера не поддерживает данное свойство.

Comment: Да нет, поддерживается. Как раз 16 версия

Comment: Попробуйте изучить этот материал - https://developer.samsung.com/internet/blog/en-us/2020/12/15/dark-mode-in-samsung-internet